# setTimeOut for button cliks in javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to make it so the user cannot press a number button until the start button is pressed.  I've searched w3schools and other sites, but cannot find a solution.  Any help would be appreciated, even if you can point me to a website.  My instructor has informed use that we would need to find any solutions to our problems online.  Even suggestions for a good javascript book would be helpful as there is no text book for the class and he doesn't teach it.

```
<body>
<h3 style="margin-left: 15px">This is Your TARGET:</h3>
<div id="randomNum" class="display" style="margin-top: -20px; margin-bottom: 30px">0</div>

<!-- Start button -->
<button onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, 5000);">Start</button>

<!-- Total value text -->
<div id="text_total">0</div>

<!-- Number buttons -->
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(1)">1</div>
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(2)">2</div>
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(3)">3</div>
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(4)" style="clear: left">4</div>
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(5)">5</div>
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(6)">6</div>
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(7)" style="clear: left; margin-bottom: 30px">7</div>
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(8)" style="margin-bottom: 30px">8</div>
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(9)" style="margin-bottom: 30px">9</div>

<h3 style="clear: left; margin-left: 58px">COUNTER!</h3>
<div id="counter" class="display" style="clear: left; margin-top: -20px">0</div>

<script>
// Variables
var total = 0;
var target;
var clicks = 0;



window.onload = randomNumber();

// Functions
function change_total(arg) { // This takes button input and changes the total value
    total = total + arg;
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    update_total();
    if (total == target) {
        alert("You win!"); // popup window with message
        total = 0; // reset for next round
        clicks = 0; // resets the click counter
        randomNumber(); //gets new number for next round
        update_total();
    }if (total > target) {
        alert("BUSTED!!");
        total = 0;
        clicks = 0;
        randomNumber();
        update_total();
        }
    update_clicks();
}

function myFunction() {
    alert("You failed to reach the target in time!");
}

function update_total() { // Updates the text on the screen to show the current total
    document.getElementById("text_total").innerHTML = total;
}

function randomNumber() { // returns a random number between 25 and 75
    target = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50) + 25);
    document.getElementById("randomNum").innerHTML = target;
}

function update_clicks() { // lets user know how many clicks
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "You clicked the mouse " + clicks + " times.";
}

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: This is not related to your question, but note that your `randomNumber()` function returns an integer in the range of 25 through 74 (not 75) inclusive. This is because `Math.random()` returns a value less than or equal to 0 and _less than_ 1. You are correct to use `Math.floor()` here, just take this into account if you need to.

Comment: Instead of using a timeout interval, how about you just show an error message if a key is pressed before the start button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try for this,

I have tested it on my end, see below,

**i just use isStart boolean variable to check is game start or not.**

```
<body>
<h3 style="margin-left: 15px">This is Your TARGET:</h3>
<div id="randomNum" class="display" style="margin-top: -20px; margin-bottom: 30px">0</div>

<!-- Start button -->
<button onclick="startGame()">Start</button>

<!-- Total value text -->
<div id="text_total">0</div>

<!-- Number buttons -->
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(1)">1</div>
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(2)">2</div>
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(3)">3</div>
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(4)" style="clear: left">4</div>
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(5)">5</div>
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(6)">6</div>
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(7)" style="clear: left; margin-bottom: 30px">7</div>
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(8)" style="margin-bottom: 30px">8</div>
<div class="number_button" onclick="change_total(9)" style="margin-bottom: 30px">9</div>

<h3 style="clear: left; margin-left: 58px">COUNTER!</h3>
<div id="counter" class="display" style="clear: left; margin-top: -20px">0</div>

<script>
// Variables
var total = 0;
var target;
var clicks = 0;



window.onload = randomNumber();
var isStart=false;
// Functions
function change_total(arg) { // This takes button input and changes the total value
if(isStart){
    total = total + arg;
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    update_total();
    if (total == target) {
        alert("You win!"); // popup window with message
        total = 0; // reset for next round
        clicks = 0; // resets the click counter
        randomNumber(); //gets new number for next round
        update_total();
        isStart=false;
    }if (total > target) {
        alert("BUSTED!!");
        total = 0;
        clicks = 0;
        randomNumber();
        update_total();
        isStart=false;
        }
    update_clicks();
    }
    else{
    alert('please start the game');
    }
}

function myFunction() {
    alert("You failed to reach the target in time!");
}

function update_total() { // Updates the text on the screen to show the current total
    document.getElementById("text_total").innerHTML = total;
}

function randomNumber() { // returns a random number between 25 and 75
    target = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50) + 25);
    document.getElementById("randomNum").innerHTML = target;
}

function update_clicks() { // lets user know how many clicks
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "You clicked the mouse " + clicks + " times.";
}
function startGame(){
isStart=true;
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to work on my end.  Now I need to work on the timer part.